# Cannot use WithMany in Entity Framework Fluent API

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I Can't use WithMany for many-to-many connection. I tried everything, and I have not idea what tha problem it could be. Please help if you have some axperience about it.

I have two models "Drink" and "DrinkCategory". every drink could have many categories, so I need many-to-many relationship.

Here is first model "Drink":

```
public class Drink
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public int DrinkId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int DrinkIngredientId { get; set; }
    public string DrinkName { get; set; }

    public virtual DrinkIngredient DrinkIngredients { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<DrinkCategory> DrinkCategories { get; set; }

}
```

It is second model "DrinkCategorie":

```
public class DrinkCategory
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public int DrinkCategoryId { get; set; }
    public string DrinkCategoryName { get; set; }
    public int? ParentDrinkCategoryId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Drink> Drinks { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my DBContext:

```
public class EatAndDrinkDbContext : DbContext
{
    public EatAndDrinkDbContext(DbContextOptions<EatAndDrinkDbContext> options) : base(options) { }
    public EatAndDrinkDbContext() { }

    public DbSet<Drink> Drinks { get; set; }
    public DbSet<DrinkCategory> DrinkCategories { get; set; }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Drink>()
         .HasMany(c => c.DrinkCategories)
         .WithMany(i => i.Drinks)
         .Map(t => t.MapLeftKey("DrinkId")
             .MapRightKey("DrinkCategoryId")
             .ToTable("DrinkDrinkCategory"));


        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```

}

Comment: `DbContextOptions` in the constructor indicates EF **Core**, not EF6 as in the question tag. EF Core does not support many-to-many with implicit junction table (has no `WithMany`, `Map` etc. fluent API), see [Relationshis - Many-to-many](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#many-to-many)

Comment: Thank you Ivan. I Did not known. Seems It is my problem. Thank you so much.

Comment: @IvanStoev thanks for the info, i'll be better if you write your comment as an answer.